# .net - SocketException 10054

Tags: .net, sockets, udp

I am writing small UDP client-server app. Server allows to connect more than 1 client.
To send message to all clients I use this code:

```
// IPEndPoints - List<IPEndPoint> where I store clients' IPEndPoints
// packet - byte[] with data
for (int i = 0; i < IPEndPoints.Count; ++i)
    server.Send(packet, packet.Length, IPEndPoints[i]);
```

To recieve messages I use this:

```
//packet - byte[] to store data
//endPoint - IPEndPoint
packet = server.Receive(ref endPoint);
```

But, when one of the clients suddenly closes the connection I still try to send message to it endPointand get SocketException with code 10054. The question is, how do I find out which client disconnected? How do I get this client's IPEndPoint to remove from IPEndPoints list? I thought that this IPEndPoint will be stored in endPoint (passed with ref), but when the exception is fired, endPoint remains untouched.

Comment: That's WSAECONNRESET, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".  But you already knew that.  These things happen, you'll need to catch that exception if you want to keep your program running.

Comment: Of course I've catched this exception, but do you mean that these exceptions will be fired until program is closed? And there is no way to get IPEndPoint of disconnected client to not send messages to disconnected client anymore?

Comment: Yes I know it. But I don't know how to get IPEndPoint to remove it from IPEndPoints array.

Comment: The client that disconnected is the one you sent the message to. But I'm surprised that you're getting WSACONNRESET via UDP. I don't see how that is possible.